# How to create a metabox that will list all my pages in a dropdown selector?

Tags: pages, metabox

I would like to have a metabox for the user to be able to select from a dropdown list one page from the website. I need to save the user choice, so I can use it later. So, my question is how can I create a metabox that will list all my pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`wp_dropdown_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages). For example

```
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post edit screens */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'post' 
    );
}

/* Prints the box content */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {

     $dropdown_args = array(
        'post_type'        => 'page'
        'name'             => 'myplugin[page]',
        'sort_column'      => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'echo'             => 1,
    );

         // Use nonce for verification
         wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename');

         //Dropdown of pages
         wp_dropdown_pages( $dropdown_args );
}
```

See also [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) on handling metabox data.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. This metabox will be use for a theme and not in a plugin.

Comment: This will work in `functions.php` too - but it is [recommended](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-create-a-functionality-plugin) to have things like this in a plug-in.

Comment: Last question. How can I retrieve the user choice?

Comment: Hook onto `save_post` then (after checking its not a revision, and checking nonce, permissions etc - [see example on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)). Inspect `$_POST`. In this example `$_POST['myplugin']['page']` will hold the ID of the selected page.